# getting a booklet layout for print and cut in half

Tags: pdf, layout, printing, imposition

I will try and make this as clear as possible but it's difficult to explain.

I want to print 2 pages per side, on each side. Normally the pattern when putting this through the printer is from left to right, with the first set of pages on the first side and the second set on the flip side.

Normally:
1-2 | 3-4.

I need a layout in which p.1 and p.4 print on the first side, with 4 on the left and 1 on the right. On the flip side, p. 2 and p. 3 respectively from left to right. So that it "wrap"s around the page.

What I need:
4-1 | 2-3

So that if you fold the page in half, you get 1-2-3-4 by flipping through as if the whole page was a booklet.

I've tried lots of pdf editors and gone into print dialogues over and over, but can't seem to get this option.

Anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is is called **IMPOSITION**

you have a large choice between many ways to perform this task if your source file is a  **pdf**. Here two of these (the easiest):

1. **pdfbklt**

   - http://www.ziddu.com/download/1794055/pdfbklt.exe.html
   - http://ge.tt/88oFY7H/v/0
   - http://goo.gl/BwzdT
   - http://dingodog.minus.com/mjhNX8Eiu

> pdfbklt -l -b A4 -p2s input.pdf

**please, take in mind that pdfbklt overwrites the input pdf file, so it is better work on a copy of your file**

> pdfbklt has the advantage to automatically insert blank pages at end
>   of your pdf file if needed to reach an integer multiple of 4 (needed
>   by impositions booklet laws)

it works in windows under dos or in linux with **wine**

---

2 -  **nup_pdf.jar** (needs java)

- http://blog.rubypdf.com/2007/08/24/how-to-make-n-up-pdf-with-free-software/

`java -jar nup_pdf.jar input.pdf output.pdf 2 x 1  -k 1`

that produces, taking for instance a 16 pages long document, this order

```
16,1
2,15
14,3
4,13
12,5
6,11
10,7
8,9
```

## PRINTING ENVELOP

```
odd side|even side
front / back of sheet paper
 _____________
|      |      |
| 16,1 | 2,15 |
|______|______|
 _____________
|      |      |
| 14,3 | 4,13 |
|______|______|
 _____________
|      |      |
| 12,5 | 6,11 |
|______|______|
 _____________
|      |      |
| 10,7 |  8,9 |
|______|______|`
```